# convert a text from a file to a list of strings in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to read a text file and extract each word from all lines to make a list of strings like below:

```
['Arise', 'But', 'It', 'Juliet', 'Who', 'already', 'and', 'breaks', 'east',
'envious', 'fair', 'grief', 'is', 'kill', 'light', 'moon', 'pale', 'sick',
'soft', 'sun', 'the', 'through', 'what', 'window', 'with', 'yonder']
```

I wrote this code:

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
lst = list()
for line in fh:
    lst.append(line.split())
print lst
print lst.sort()
```

when I sort it in the end it gives nothing but a None.
I get this unexpected result!

```
[['But', 'soft', 'what', 'light', 'through', 'yonder', 'window', 'breaks'],
['It', 'is', 'the', 'east', 'and', 'Juliet', 'is', 'the', 'sun'], ['Arise', 
'fair', 'sun', 'and', 'kill', 'the', 'envious', 'moon'], ['Who', 'is',
'already', 'sick', 'and', 'pale', 'with', 'grief']]
None
```

I am totally lost. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the format of the text file?

Comment: Its a plane text file.But soft what light through yonder window breaks
It is the east and Juliet is the sun
Arise fair sun and kill the envious moon
Who is already sick and pale with grief

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got it. Here is what I want.

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname).read().split()
lst = list()
for word in fh:
    if word in lst:
        continue
    else:
        lst.append(word)
print sorted(lst)
```

Comment: `set` is faster.  That is all you need, `print(sorted(set(open(fname).read().split())))`

Answer (score 3):

`.split()` returns a list. So you are appending the returned list to `lst`. Instead you want to concat the 2 lists:

```
lst += line.split()
```

`.sort()` sorts the array in place, and does not return the sorted array. You can either use

```
print sorted(lst)
```

or

```
lst.sort()
print lst
```

Comment: An alternative to the concatenation operator is the equivalent [`list.extend()`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).

Comment: But then lst.sort() gives nothing but None.

Comment: @Mehmood, `.sort()` sorts your list in place, and does not return the sorted list

Answer (score 3):

Use `extend` instead of `append`,

```
lst = list()

fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
with open(fname) as fh:
    for line in fh:
        lst.extend(line.rstrip.split()) # `rstrip` removes trailing whitespace characters, like `\n`

print(lst)
lst.sort() # Sort the items of the list in place
print(lst)
```

---

[Python - append vs. extend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/python-append-vs-extend)

- `append`: Appends object at end.
- `extend`: Extends list by appending elements from the iterable.

Answer (score 1):

Read the entire file with [`file.read()`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) and split that string wherever there is whitespace with [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
with open(raw_input("Enter file name: "), 'r') as f:
    words = f.read().split()
print words
print sorted(words)
```

Comment: I am limited to use only split(), append() and sort() commands.

Comment: @Mehmood you said you were limited in the functions you can use, but then you posted an answer that completely copied my method. What gives?

Comment: You didn't use append() method, rather you used nice programming skills, which I hope to achieve this mastery some day. I need to write the code in a simple way using above mentioned commands, The programm should also exclude repetitive strings in the list.